# setting blob to null using PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, blob, binarystream

I am creating webapplication using JSF2.0 where in mysql, I am storing images using datatype as `MEDIUMBLOB`.

To insert values, I am using PreparedStatement as shown below.

```
PreparedStatement psmnt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO sketchesSG002003 (userid, imageTitle, imageData, drawingComments) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
psmnt.setLong(1, personalInfoId);
psmnt.setString(2, sketchesSG002003Title);

try {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(sketchesSG002003ImageUpload.getName());
    File image = new File(fileName);
    InputStream fis = sketchesSG002003ImageUpload.getInputStream();
    psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, (int) sketchesSG002003ImageUpload.getSize());
} catch (Exception e) {
    psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, null);
}
psmnt.setString(4, sketchesSG002003Comments);
i = psmnt.executeUpdate();
```

However I am getting error as

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
```

Some part of Stacktrace is

```
 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
```

I believe above error is for statement `psmnt.setBinaryStream(3, null);`

**My question is how can I set binary data as Null or Nothing?**

Comment: This problem is not JSF related.

Comment: I know, however as I was using that technology, I thought to include it... nothing else...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is going wrong these days? I get solution after I ask question :(

`psmnt.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.BLOB);` did the trick.

Comment: is there any difference between LongBlob and normal blob in this case?